# How to control webview landscape and portrait in android?

Tags: android, webview

In my application, I am using webview for displaying html page. Html page contains an youtube video.
   In portrait mode, it is loading and working properly.But when the orientation changes to landscape mode, the page is again loading (recreating) and video in html page is displaying only half size. I used android:configChanges="orientation" in manifest file but not working...and also video should continue when orientatation

Here is my code...,

```
         webb=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.weeeb1);
                 webb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                    webb.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
                        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
                        {}
                    });

                    webb.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
                        @Override
                        public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl)
                        {
                            // Handle the error
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
                        {
                            view.loadUrl(url);
                            return true;
                        }
                    });
                    webb.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
                    //webb.setInitialScale(12);
                    webb.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
                    webb.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
                    webb.setPadding(0,0,0,0); 
                    webb.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index1.html");

Portrait mode

    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/row33"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_below="@+id/titletext"
          android:fillViewport="false"
          android:scrollbars="none"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          >
        <LinearLayout
          android:id="@+id/row35"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="600dp"
          android:layout_below="@+id/row33"
          android:layout_margin="8dp" 
          android:orientation="vertical" 
          android:layout_weight="1"
          >
    <LinearLayout
          android:id="@+id/row34"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="260dp"
          android:layout_below="@+id/row33"
          android:layout_marginLeft="6px"
          android:layout_marginRight="17px"
          android:orientation="horizontal" 
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="#1C2F69"
          >


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/gimage1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="10px"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30px"
            android:layout_marginRight="10px"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10px"
            android:background="@drawable/natureimage4"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/gimage2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="10px"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10px"
            android:layout_marginRight="30px"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10px"
            android:background="@drawable/natureimage5"
            />

     </LinearLayout>
      <WebView 
         android:id="@+id/weeeb1" 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:layout_marginLeft="6px"
          android:layout_marginRight="17px"
          android:layout_marginTop="5px"
          android:layout_marginBottom="29dp"
         android:layout_below="@+id/row35"
          android:layout_weight="1"
         />
         </LinearLayout>
     </ScrollView>


Landscape mode

<ScrollView android:id="@+id/row33"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_below="@+id/titlemain"
      android:fillViewport="false"
      android:scrollbars="none"
      android:layout_weight="1">
    <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/row35"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="600dp"
      android:layout_below="@+id/row33"
      android:layout_marginLeft="190dp" 
      android:layout_marginRight="190dp"
      android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
      android:orientation="vertical" 
      android:layout_weight="1">
<LinearLayout

          android:id="@+id/row34"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="200dp"
          android:layout_below="@+id/row33"
          android:orientation="horizontal" 
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:background="#1C2F69">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/gimage1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="10px"
            android:layout_marginLeft="35px"
            android:layout_marginRight="25px"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10px"
            android:background="@drawable/natureimage4" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/gimage2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_marginTop="10px"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25px"
            android:layout_marginRight="35px"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10px"
            android:background="@drawable/natureimage5" />

     </LinearLayout>
      <WebView 
         android:id="@+id/weeeb1" 
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginBottom="9dp"
         android:layout_below="@+id/row35"
         android:layout_weight="1" />
         </LinearLayout>
     </ScrollView>


Please suggest me the solution....
```

Comment: So what is the real question? You want to be the video always in portrait mode or just rotate the screen without reloading the webpage?

Comment: 1. In webview - displayed html page..                               2. in that html page, youtube video is there                        Problem is 1. whn i am rotating screen from portraite to landscape... in landscape mode the video is displaying only half    size                                                                 2. whn i am playing video,it is not continuing on rotation..

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to avoid rotation. Add this to fix the activity for portrait orientation only in manifest.

```
android:screenOrientation="portrait"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this in your manifest. It may help you.

```
android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Thank you for joining the community! We appreciate your answer. However to make this answer better you should try to use markdown to make your code appear as if it is code, not just text. Check out [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)